# When trying to use export as csv i get only id

Tags: django

I am using django export as CSV, i have this model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    disc_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default="Unpaid")
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(
        PaymentMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    order_status = models.ForeignKey(OrderStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    total = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
```

i get everything but I am getting product id and order status id

Here I want product name status name but I am getting product ID, status ID
Here is the screenshot :
[image]

```
def export_orders(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Orders.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['id', 'Customer', 'Full Name', 'Phone Number', 'address', 'product', 'quantity', 'price', 'total', 'Payment Status', 'Order Status'])

    orders = Order.objects.all().values_list('id', 'customer', 'fname', 'phone', 'address', 'product', 'quantity', 'price', 'total', 'status', 'order_status')
    for order in orders:
        writer.writerow(order)

    return response
```

Comment: if this not for learning purpose, then look at https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Use double underscores to access the value for the foreign key fields and try this:

```
orders = Order.objects.all().values_list('product__value', 'order_status__value', ...other fields)
#this is equal to order.product.value and order.order_status.value
```

**Please replace 'value' here with the name of the foreign object's attribute.**